# Multiple numpy place calls yield odd results

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to create an 8-bit 1-channel mask used for use in some image operations. I have an image that has certain pixels filled with fuscia (`255, 0, 255`) in the `original` image which indicates that pixel should be used in masking.

My idea is to simply copy the original picture, then replace all the fuscia pixels with white, and all the non-fuscia pixels with black. I am using `numpy.place` to do this. It appears, however, to only really "apply" the last `place` operation.

For example, in the code below, I am trying to first set all the fuscia pixels to white, and then all the non-fuscia pixels to black. However, when I go and actually save the image out and look at it, only the non-fuscia pixels have been turned black.

```
mask = original.copy()
np.place(mask, mask == (255, 0, 255), (255, 255, 255))
np.place(mask, mask != (255, 0, 255), (0, 0, 0))
mask = mask.reshape((h, w, 3))
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

## `original`

[image]

## `mask`

[image]

I expect the fuscia area to be white, but it isn't. It is the greyscale version of the fuscia color (`112, 112, 112`)

I'm fairly new to numpy, so I may even be barking up the wrong tree and there could be an easier way to do this. What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier way to do what I'm describing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could use a boolean array as the mask. For example:

```
mask = np.any(original==[255, 0, 255], axis=-1)
```

Now you can do `original[mask]` to get only the magenta pixels, or `orignal[~mask]` to get the others.

You'll find you can't overwrite `original` but you can overwrite a copy:

```
newimg = original.copy()
newimg[mask] = [255, 255, 255]
newimg[~mask] = [0, 0, 0]
```

By the way, I think you're 'supposed' to use [masked arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) for this sort of thing, but I never got to grips with those.